# Where to find the up to date catholic missals for each languages?

Tags: catholicism, mass, missal

I was able to find a latin missal (cf. [MISSALE
ROMANUM](http://www.sanctamissa.org/en/resources/missale-romanum.pdf), from 1962), but what I would like to find are translations in other languages (and the more recent "editio typica tertia"). I guess those should be all available on the vatican website, but where?

I am specifically interested in the Korean translation, as I am currently living there and it would help a lot in following the mass and learning the language.

Ideally, it would be best if I could find those in an editable format, so I can merge Latin and Korean in one pdf or ebook.

Edit : I found the Latin editio typica tertia on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/MISSALEROMANUMEditioTypicaTertiaLibreriaEditriceVaticana2002). It is 1220 pages and it looks like the real deal. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can confirm?
This is the kind of edition I would like to find in other languages...

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: You might try asking traditional priest in Korea where to look. After all it would be in their interest also.

Comment: @KenGraham I asked my parish priest a few months ago. He told me it's not possible to buy Latin/Korean missals in Korea. I hoped that I could at least find an old pre-Vatican II missal as I assume they were Latin/Korean at the time, but he told me no. His English is not that good so I couldn't ask more precisely...

Comment: The  Latin Missal you make reference to is of the 1920–1955 usage. It is the real deal insofar as the Tridentine Missal goes. But if you want the 1962 edition  you must simply ignore most Octave Feasts as seen [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgical_colours)

Comment: Contact the [**SSPX in Korea**](http://www.sspx.or.kr/) (URL discovered from [MesseMonde](http://messemonde.free.fr/Wikini/wakka.php?wiki=RepubliqueDeCoree)). They would know.

Answer (score 2):

A [search for the *Missale Romanum* on the Vatican website](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Avatican.va+missale+romanum&ia=web) reveals that it is apparently unavailable, though the *General Instruction for the Roman Missal* seems to be available in multiple languages. This is in line with the English translation of the Roman Missal, which is unavailable on the websites of the US Conference of Catholic Bishops or the Catholic Bishops' Conference of England and Wales. It's not clear whether this is for copyright reasons or for some other reason.

According to the [Union of Catholic Asian News](http://www.ucanews.com/news/korean-church-to-update-missal/78799), the Catholic Bishops' Conference of Korea has decided only within the last several weeks to authorize a translation based on the *editio typica tertia*. This decision does not seem to appear on the bishops' conference website.

If your parish pastor is unable to help you find a missal, perhaps you could check with [the Bishops' Conference](http://english.cbck.or.kr/).

Comment: Thank you! I asked in my Korean parish but they do not use any latin/korean missal as they don't have a tradition to do that. I will try to ask editors directly for the latin version, and otherwise use the older version if they cannot help. I'll also try contacting the Korean Bishops' conference, and will post back infos here later. I have trouble understanding why would the Catholic church prevent a larger access to those translations, as it can only help spread the gospel...

Comment: I got a very fast answer from the Bishops' Conference, but negative : "It is very regrettable to say that we cannot give you a pdf file of the Korean/Latin missal, because it was made and used only for Bishops during the Plenary Asssembly, in order to help them compare the Koran translation with the Latin for new translation of the Missal.
 
And we do not have old Korean/Latin missals used before the Vatican II council.
 
Sorry for not being of any help to you."